# Why would "Assembly Deployment Target" be disabled, in a non-sandboxed solution?

Tags: visual-studio, gac

I have a visual studio project where I am trying to GAC the dll that is created.  My problem is that when I click on the project and look at the "Assembly Deployment Target" property it is disabled (greyed out) and has no value selected.  From what I understand this is what happens if you have a sandboxed solution, but this particular project is not a sandboxed solution.

Why would this happen?  Is there a way that I can specify that I want it deployed to the GAC?

Comment: Are you developing on the machine where SP2010 is installed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Assembly Deployment Target" property is disabled at a sandboxed solution, you're correct. But it's also disabled when developing a farm solution when the property "Include Assembly in Package" in the same properties window is set to False.

Can you verify this setting?

Comment: Hello, when developing a farm solution what is the purpose of setting the property "Include Assembly in Package" to True? Where does the wsp get deployed to content db or filesystem?